# iOS : In App Purchasing

Tags: ios, itunes

I am using in app purchasing for first time. i have created an app in iTunes Connect and add 1 in-app purchase. Is it necessary to submit the app for testing in app purchases?? I want to get in app purchases list in my corona code. For this is it necessary that app should be available in AppStore??

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here [Troy Brant](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) has a great tutorial for In-App Purchases which could help you a lot.

You have to submit once, and reject your binary in order to add your in-app's to your application, than before you press ready to upload binary, you can edit your in-app's from detail page of your app.